# IOS: animation with UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiimageview

I have two imageViews that I call firstView and secondView; I have to do an animation that move a third imageView that I call imageView3. This imageView3 is inside firstView and I do this code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[imageView3 setFrame:frameinSecondView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
//[imageView3 removeFromSuperview];
//[secondView addSubview:imageView3];
```

with this code I can move imageView3 to secondView but the problem is that I'm not able to set imageView3 in the correct frame "frameinSeconView"; instead if I use the commented code

```
[imageToMove removeFromSuperview];
[scrollViewAlfabeto addSubview:imageToMove];
```

imageView3 go on the correct frame but I don't see the animation because when it starts its animation, imageview3 disappear from firstView ad appear when it go on secondView

How Can I solve to have a correct animation, with a correct frame between these two imageViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass imageView3 from 1 to 2 right?
Remove it from imageView1 and place it on the windowView, do the animation from 1 to 2 and *wait* to end the animations to remove from windowView and insert into imageView2

how to *wait*? ... well there is a [sentence something] structure that do that, but i dont know how is it, instead of that (cause ive never found how) i started to use "animation blocks" :D

what is an animation block?
block: object that means an action; 
below is an example of an animation using block objects block1, block2  (CODE PARTC)

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                 animations: block1
                 completion: block2
    ];
```

It means that it will do actions defined in block1, as if they were inside begin-commit animation sentences, and (the beautiful part) after its COMPLETION they will do the actions in block2! :D!

but what is a f----ng block?; well...
THIS IS A F----NG BLOCK!:

*Block that returns void (CODE PARTA):*

```
    void (^block1)(void) = ^{
    centerPortrait.frame = frame1;
    if (lookingMenu==NO)
        listTableView.frame = frameT1;
    };
```

*Block that returns BOOL (after completion: you need a bool) and that have another animation inside (CODE PARTB)*

```
    void (^block2)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL got){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:halfDuration delay:0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                     animations:^{
                         centerPortrait.image = image;
                         centerPortrait.frame = frame2;
                         if (lookingMenu==YES)
                             listTableView.frame = frameT2;
                     } 
                     completion:nil
     ];
    };
```

I've used this to make a fake rotation of an image hohohoho
Anyways if u didnt got it, the order is PARTA,B,C :P

Read this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1

is where i got how to use blocks :D, and heres an useful tutorial of the great RAYWENDERLICH:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

Hope it helps!