# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]'

Tags: ios, xcode, runtime-error

Having trouble with the following bit of code:

```
int count = [imageArray count];
for (int i = 0; i <= count ; i++)
{
     UIImage *currentImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
     UIImage *nextImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i +1];
     self.imageview.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
[self.view addSubview:self.imageview];
CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
crossFade.duration = 5.0;
crossFade.fromValue = (__bridge id)(currentImage.CGImage);
crossFade.toValue = (__bridge id)(nextImage.CGImage);
[self.imageview.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
    self.imageview.image = nextImage;

};
```

Very new to iOS coding so any help would be appreciated, just need to know how to stop the error.

Comment: Did you try reading the message??

Comment: No need to severely downvote the OP. Yes, the answer is obvious. And yes, he could find the answer himself, but still... @Steffan: welcome to SO. Next time please do read the message debugger sends you :) And don't forget to accept the answer that helped you solve the problem. You should also take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: i did read the message, but evidently didnt know how to fix the problem, hence the question.

Comment: You mean you hadn't a clue as to how to debug the problem.  What you do is to break up the complex expression you're having trouble with into a series of simple assignments, then examine (with debugger or NSLog) the results of those simple statements.  (You should have learned this skill with previous languages you worked with -- it's nothing unique to Objective-C.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to this piece of code:

```
UIImage *nextImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i +1];
```

and the condition you used : `i <= count`

Suppose your array contains 6 objects. Then the loop will run from 0 - 6. Array index starts from 0, so the 6th elements index is 5. If you try to fetch the objectAtIndex:6 a crash will occur.

Like wise you are taking the image at i+1 if the i is 5, then it'll try to fetch i+1 th means 6th element. Probably a crash.

Change your method like:

```
int count = [imageArray count];
for (int i = 0; i <count-1 ; i++)
{
     UIImage *currentImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
     UIImage *nextImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i +1];
     self.imageview.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
     [self.view addSubview:self.imageview];
     CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
     crossFade.duration = 5.0;
     crossFade.fromValue = (__bridge id)(currentImage.CGImage);
     crossFade.toValue = (__bridge id)(nextImage.CGImage);
     [self.imageview.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
     self.imageview.image = nextImage;

};
```

Comment: yeah thats got rid of the error, thanks.
Any idea why only the last 2 images show up when i run it though? there are 7 in the array

Comment: @SteffanDavies: that's due to the loop, the loop will execute all of a sudden. o you will see the last two images only.

Comment: how would i stop that happening? sorry for the noob questions haha Im still in school and only started learning Objective C about a week ago, other than that all i know is a bit of VB

Comment: @SteffanDavies: you need to use the UIView animate method. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081506/ios-animation-with-uiimageview . On completion block you need to recursively call the animation method.

Comment: @SteffanDavies: this is a good tutorial to start with : http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. Your array has 7 objects in it. This means the valid indexes are 0 through 6.

Your `for` loop is written to iterate from 0 through 7. So you should write it as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

You had `i <= count` instead of `i < count`.

But there is another issue. Inside the loop you get the current image at index `i` and the next image at index `i + 1`. So this means that when you get the current image at index 6, the next image will be retrieved from index 7. This will make it crash again.

Most likely you want to stop the loop even sooner. It should be:

```
for (int = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
```